# Sharing several variables using one file

Tags: c, pointers, shared-memory, offset, mmap

I'm trying to share two variables between two different processes: an array and an int. And I want to use the same file. When I call mmap(), and using the offset as I think it works, I get a segmentation fault when I try to use the int.

```
  buf = (int *)mmap(NULL,N*sizeof(int),PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,compart,0);
  count = (int *)mmap(NULL,sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,compart,N*sizeof(int));
  *count = 0;
```

What I do is  locate the array at the beginning of the file, and the int at the position following the size of the array.

Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Start by checking the return values: `if (buf == MAP_FAILED) perror("buf mapping failed"); ...` Probably your `mmap` call is failing.